# Set standard language for a new, empty file in Notepad++ without PlugIns

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

When creating a new, empty document in Notepad++ (either by pressing CTRL-N or File->New), NPP sets the default style, but no language highlighting until the current file is saved with an extension that sets the language.

I ship NPP portable along a compiler I wrote, so the language will always be the same (all other languages were removed). How can I modify NPP is such a way that the new file is already syntax highlighted?

Hint: I am not looking for templates (as provided by the NewFile Browser PlugIn).

Comment: Just an additional question: Do you have neccessary means for recompiling NPP code on your own?

Comment: @miroxlav Yes, but I consider this the last resort. But if there is no way around it - so be it.

Comment: Actually, NPP is not so feature-rich here as you would expect. IMHO no one seriosly needed these things so they are not implemented. You can download NPP sources and check method for new document initialization, which also chooses default syntax coloring, by yourself. (That will be the same method you will most likely need to modify to switch to preferred highlighter.) Do you think you need help with this checking from someone? (e.g. from me? :) )

Comment: @miroxlav Well, time to set up VS again. The bug really is that any UDL is not visible in the Default dropdown, but if I bother to recompile, I'll also remove other unwanted features. I'll get back to you if I need help ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the way to go is to modify source code of NPP and create your own build which will have desired feature.

Alternative approach is to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) at the NPP project page and wait until it gets implemented. But there is a risk you can be waiting too long. :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings->Preferences->New Document and set Default language.

Comment: Only Scintilla languages are available in this setting.